# Python: Line that does not start with #

Tags: python, regex

I have a file that contains something like

> # comment
>   # comment
>    not a comment
>
> # comment
>   # comment
>    not a comment

I'm trying to read the file line by line and only capture lines that does not start with #. What is wrong with my code/regex?

```py
import re

def read_file():
    pattern = re.compile("^(?<!# ).*")

    with open('list') as f:
        for line in f:
            print pattern.findall(line)
```

Original code captures everything instead of expected.

Comment: The lookbehind checks for something *before* the current position, and a lookahead checks what is *after* the current position. Use a lookahead if you really need a regex. But you do not really need a regex here.

Comment: Do you have to do with with `regex`?...you can do it just with `buitl-in` methods...saves you trouble of `regex`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An alternative and yet simple approach is to only check if the first `char` of each line you read does not contain `#` character:

```
def read_file():

    with open('list') as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line.lstrip().startswith('#'):
                print line
```

Comment: But I think OP is asking for *why doesn't `^(?<!# ).*` work in this case*, not *how to do this*.

Comment: Yes. I guess this one works. But do you know why the regex doesn't work?

Comment: @Mico no pblm...Still I will update my answer with `regex`

Answer (score 13):

[Iron Fist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34129925/996114) shows the way you should probably do this; however, if you want to know what was wrong with your regex anyway, it should have been this:

```
^[^#].*
```

Explanation:

- `^` - match beginning of line.
- `[^#]` - match something that is not `#`. `[^...]` is how you say not to match something (just replace `...` with whatever characters you do not want to match. For example, `[^ABC123]` will match a character that is none of A, B, C, 1, 2, or 3. Don't let the `^` that indicates the beginning of a line/string confuse you here. These two `^`'s are totally unrelated.
- `.*` - match zero or more of anything else.

**EDIT:**

The reason `^(?<!# ).*` does NOT discriminate between `# comment` and `not a comment` is that `(?<!#)` checks the text *before* the current position. The engine looks for `#` before the first symbol after the start of string, and since there is no `#` before the start of string, any line is a match for `.*` subpattern. To really check if the first symbol is `#`, you just need to use `^#.*` regex. Or, if there can be leading whitespace, `^\s*#`.

Comment: @stribizhev How so? I'm certainly not an expert on negative loosbehind assertions. Please correct me.

Comment: See my comment to the question. The first one.

Comment: @stribizhev But what exactly is wrong with my answer. I don't see any issues.

Comment: *.\* is greedy and matches the entire line INCLUDING the # or # comment* is irrelevant. *the negative lookbehind assertion (?<!# ) can't detect the #, because it already is swallowed up by the .\** is just wrong. **Lookarounds do not consume text**.

Comment: I updated this answer with the correct explanation according to @stribizhev if someone can accept it.

Comment: @stribizhev Then why does `^(?<!#\s)comment` work for OP's text, but `^(?<!#\s).*comment` does not?

Comment: @stribizhev I said nothing about the look around consuming the text.

Comment: @stribizhev: After reading your edit, I now understand your point. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeCovington Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Because:

> `(?!# )` Negative **Lookahead** - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
>   `(?<!# )` Negative **Lookbehind** - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex `#`.
>   <sub>which from regex101</sub>

It means it only match `#` behind that. So what I mean is:

```
>>> re.search('foo(?!bar)', 'foobar')
>>> re.search('foo(?<!bar)', 'foobar')  # doesn't work
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='foo'>


>>> re.search('(?<!bar)foo', 'barfoo')
>>> re.search('(?!bar)foo', 'barfoo')   # doesn't work
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(3, 6), match='foo'>
```

It's because you used the wrong token. So the answer is very simple:

> Use `(?!bar)` if you **don't want some string *after* the `bar`**.
>   Use `(?<!bar)` if you **don't want some string *before* the `bar`**.

Comment: Why answer starts with **Because**?

Answer (score 2):

Use `match` function in this case- since it will check in the beginning.

So expression will be `\s*[^#]`- for sanity i use `\s` to pass whitespaces.

OP's code will be-

```
def read_file():
    pattern = re.compile("\s*[^#]")
    with open(r"C:\test.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            if pattern.match(line):
                    print line
read_file()
```

EDIT-

A bit explanation why OP's pattern is not working-

When you use `.` it means **all** except **line break character**. So when you write `^(?<!# ).*` it means `any` character (except line break- it includes `#` damn it!) that has not `#` before- ultimately it becomes any string (except line break variant) starts with `any` character.

See <kbd>[LIVE DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wQ2gZ4/1)</kbd>

Solution:

Try `negation` like `^(?<!# )[^#]`